# Excel: Reference non-zero cells

Tags: vba, excel, indexing, excel-formula

I'm trying to list 50 rows x 8 columns of cells (defined 'allhazards') into one column

However each cell in myhazards is referencing other sheets and contain 0's where there is no text to be referenced.

When I list the data in 'allhazards' in a single column using this formula:

```
=INDEX(allhazards,1+INT((ROW($A1)-1)/COLUMNS(allhazards)),MOD(ROW($A1)-1+COLUMNS(allhazards),COLUMNS(allhazards))+1)
```

(then drag down the column to get all of the cells from 'allhazards')

How do I implement this:

***if cell in 'allhazards' is 0, do not reference this cell, move to next row
...then reference next row's columns until cell is 0, then move to next row
...keep doing this until there are no rows left to be referenced***

eg. if 'allhazards' contained these cells (eg. 2 rows x 8 columns):

```
hello how are 0 0 0 0 0
good  0   0   0 0 0 0 0
```

It should produce this when dragging down the formula:

```
hello
how
are
good
```

but not this:

```
hello
how
are
0
0
0
0
0
good
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: Are you OK with a user defined function created in VBA that you can use on the worksheet?

Answer (score 1):

I created a UDF for your situation. Please place the following procedure in a standard code module.

```
Public Function MATRIX2VECTOR(r As Range)
    Dim i&, j&, k&, v, m, o
    v = r
    ReDim o(1 To Application.Caller.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
            m = v(i, j)
            If Len(m) Then
                If m <> 0 Then
                    k = k + 1
                    o(k, 1) = v(i, j)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For k = k + 1 To UBound(o): o(k, 1) = "": Next
    MATRIX2VECTOR = o
End Function
```

Now you can call it in a formula from the worksheet just like any of the built-in functions.

## 1

Select a vertical range of cells tall enough to accommodate the transposed data.

## 2

Click in the Formula Bar at the top of Excel.

## 3

Enter this formula:

```
=MATRIX2VECTOR(allhazards)
```

## 4

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Hi there and thank you for your time and effort. I followed your method and am getting #VALUE! errors in every cell down the list. The data 'allhazards' are a group of cells referencing text from other sheets. Is there a reason why this is happening? Cheers

Comment: @Jared There should be no problem with the cells within the named range pulling data from other sheets. But you can test by copying and pasting the values into 'allhazards'. Does it work then? Are you confirming the formula with Control-Shift-Enter?

Comment: @Jared Can you send me a copy where it is not working? I'm sure I can sort it quickly? My email address is: daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: @Jared Good morning. Were you able to get it going? I'm still available to help if you'd like to email me. Can likely get it sorted virtually instantly.

Comment: Hi there, I have a rather large workbook and have been looking for non-VBA methods (as I'm not familiarly acquainted with VBA) but will try and remove the sheet for you to take a look at later today (was rushed for time yesterday and apologise for the delay) Cheers :)

Comment: @Jared No worries. Send it when you have time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in a non-VBA solution:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>COUNTIF(allhazards,"<>0"),"",INDIRECT(TEXT(AGGREGATE(15,6,(10^5*ROW(allhazards)+COLUMN(allhazards))/(allhazards<>0),ROWS($1:1)),"R0C00000"),0))`

Copy down as required.

This will be more efficient if you use a single helper cell to store the number of non-zero entries in *allhazards*, and also store the `ROW`/`COLUMN` portion as a Defined Name. For example, if you put:

`=COUNTIF(allhazards,"<>0")`

in e.g. J1, and define, in Name Manager, *Arry1* as:

`=10^5*ROW(allhazards)+COLUMN(allhazards)`

then the main formula becomes:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>$J$1,"",INDIRECT(TEXT(AGGREGATE(15,6,Arry1/(allhazards<>0),ROWS($1:1)),"R0C00000"),0))`

If your data is in a different sheet to that housing the results, simply include the sheet name containing the data, viz:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>$J$1,"",INDIRECT("'YourSheetName'!"&TEXT(AGGREGATE(15,6,Arry1/(allhazards<>0),ROWS($1:1)),"R0C00000"),0))`

Regards

Comment: Hi there. The first bit of code you provided only works when I'm in the same sheet as the data 'allhazards' is stored in. I would like to use the code in a different sheet to where my data is stored. Is this possible? Cheers

Comment: Sure. Have added to the foot of my post. Note that the single apostrophes and exclamation mark surrounding the sheet name are deliberate, and should be included.

Comment: My sheet containing allhazards is called Program, I tried replacing 'YourSheetName' with 'Program' (keeping the single apostrophes there) but it all evaluates to 0, I tried evaluating the formula and it stopped short with a 'this formula may be a circular reference', any ideas? Once again I want to kindly thank you for your time to help me.

Comment: And you didn't enter the formula anywhere within the range allhazards?